# Why is my data set preview not showing the data from my stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataset

I can't return the data on my dataset even when I preview it and input the parameters needed. But when going to the stored procedure that the dataset is pointing to then it will show the data.

Here is my data set preview data:

[image: Dataset]

And here is my stored procedure to which the data set is connected to:

[image: Stored procedure]

The `WHERE` statement values are the same

**EDIT**

Here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_viewTerminalXZSupport]
    @ReadingDate Datetime,
    @machine     varchar
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  
        h.Machine,
        CAST(h.DateStamp AS DATE) as DateTran,
        SalesInvoice,
        SUM(i.Quantity) totalquantity, 
        SUM(i.TotalAmount) totalnetamaount,
        SUM(IIF(i.quantity > 0, i.VATableSalesOntotalAmount, 0)) AS VATableSalesOntotalAmount,
        SUM(i.TotalAmount - i.VATableSalesOntotalAmount) AS VatAmount,
        SUM(IIF(i.quantity > 0, i.Quantity, 0)) AS SalesQty,
        SUM(IIF(i.quantity > 0, i.Quantity * i.Soldsrp, 0)) AS SalesGross,
        SUM(IIF(i.quantity > 0, i.DiscountAmount, 0)) AS SalesDiscount,
        SUM(IIF(i.quantity > 0, i.TotalAmount, 0)) AS SalesACD,
        SUM(IIF(i.quantity > 0, i.VatExcemptGrossSales, 0)) AS VatExcemptGrossSales,
        SUM(IIF(i.quantity > 0, i.NonVatGrossSales, 0)) AS NonVATGrossSales,
        SUM(IIF(i.quantity > 0, i.ZeroRatedGrossSales , 0)) AS ZeroRatedGrossSales,
        IIF(m.code = 'CASH', sp.Amount, 0.00) AS TotalCash, 
        IIF(m.code = 'AMEX', sp.Amount, 0.00) AS TotalAMEX,
        IIF(m.code = 'MSTR', sp.Amount, 0.00) AS TotalMSTR,
        IIF(m.code = 'VISA', sp.Amount, 0.00) AS TotalVISA,
        IIF(m.code = 'BITC', sp.Amount, 0.00) AS TotalBitCoin,
        IIF(m.code = 'EPS', sp.Amount, 0.00) AS TotalEPS,
        IIF(m.code = 'LOYAL1', sp.Amount, 0.00) AS TotalLoyal1,
        IIF(m.code = 'GC1', sp.Amount, 0.00) AS GC1
    FROM
        CSHR_SalesItems i
    INNER JOIN 
        CSHR_SalesHeader h ON h.SalesOrderNum = i.SalesOrderNum
    INNER JOIN 
        PAYMENT_SalesPayment sp ON sp.SalesOrderNum = i.SalesOrderNum
    INNER JOIN
        PAYMENT_Methods m ON m.id = sp.MethodID 
    --where     
    --    CAST(h.DateStamp AS DATE) = @ReadingDate AND i.Machine = @machine
    WHERE
        CAST(h.DateStamp AS DATE) = '2016-03-01' 
        AND i.Machine = 'DESKTOP-SRJ101J'
    GROUP BY
        h.Machine, CAST(h.DateStamp AS DATE),
        SalesInvoice, sp.Amount, m.Code
END
```

Comment: It would help immensely if you showed us the code for your stored procedure. And you do know that you can execute stored procedures in SQL Server Management Studio as well? Is the output from the stored procedure even there?

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes around the values?  '2016-03-01' and 'DESKTOP-SRJ101J'

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I've updated my question

Comment: Catch with profiler what exactly goes to the server.

Comment: @IvanStarostin What do you mean? sorry

Comment: @devlincarnate Still won't show it.

Comment: `sql profiler` tool can catch what query exactly goes to server with actual parameter values.

Comment: if it is unavailable/can't use - put raiserror inside your SP with parameter values as error message.

Comment: The most important question has not been answered: does the SP return results when you execute it in the Management Studio?

Comment: Well, I think I got it. Thanks to @IvanStarostin. Using the profiler tool, I was able to trace the incoming query then I found out that the parameter was defaulted to 1 on the varchar machine. Thank you for that.